# RStudio cannot find any package after laptop restart

Tags: r

My R script worked fine in RStudio (Version 0.98.1091) on Windows 7. Then I restarted my laptop, entered again in RStudio and now it provides the following error messages each time I want to execute my code:

```
cl <- makeCluster(mc); # build the cluster
Error: could not find function "makeCluster"
> registerDoParallel(cl)
Error: could not find function "registerDoParallel"
> fileIdndexes <- gsub("\\.[^.]*","",basename(SF))
Error in basename(SF) : object 'SF' not found
```

These error messages are slightly different each time I run the code. It seems that RStudio cannot find any function that is used in the code.

I restarted R Session, cleaned Workspace, restarted RStudio. Nothing helps.

It must be noticed that after many attempts to execute the code, it finally was initialized. However, after 100 iterations, it crashed with the message related to unavailability of localhost.

Comment: A side note: consider using [pacrat](http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) for "big" projects

Answer (score 0):

Add `library(*the package needed/where the function is*)` for each of the packages you're using.

Comment: Well, I added all the libraries. As I said my code was working perfectly. The issue occurred after restarting the laptop.

Comment: The code works perfectly as long as you're in the same session with the libraries / packages loaded. Once you restart RStudio, you'll need to reload them. Does it work now, anyway?

Comment: At the beginning of my saved script, I have these lines of code: library(gbm)
library(DMwR)
library(outliers)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(caret)
library(signal)
library(data.table)

Comment: As far as I understand, this is enough to mention libraries at the beginning of the script. Or do I need to newly install all of these libraries?

Comment: Mentioning them should be enough, so no need to reinstall everything every time.